# OWIN-hosted Nancy Module Calling RequiresAuthentication sends back 401

Tags: nancy, owin, katana

I have a Nancy module like this.

```
public class HomeModule : NancyModule
{
    public HomeModule()
    {
        this.RequiresAuthentication();

        var context = this.Context; // this is null

        Get["/"] = x =>
        {
            return "Hello";
        };
    }
}
```

A OWIN middleware sets `User` property of `OwinRequest` object to a `ClaimsPrincipal` with authenticated identity. If I break inside the module and see Thread.CurrentPrincipal, it is set correctly to the `ClaimsPrincipal` I set earlier in the middleware. Yet, `RequriesAuthentication` sends back 401. BTW, context is null inside the module. What is it that I'm doing wrong?

Some of the NuGet packages of interest that I use are

```
<package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="1.1.0-beta2" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener" version="1.1.0-beta2" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.Hosting" version="1.1.0-beta2" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Nancy" version="0.17.1" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Nancy.Owin" version="0.17.1" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
```

Answer (score 1):

RequiresAuthentication is based on Nancy IUserIdentity implementation, then you will need another approach to validate your ClaimsPrincipal identity.

See this link for a glimpse:
http://dhickey.ie/post/2014/01/04/Introducing-NancyMSOwinSecurity.aspx

And this for the code:
https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy.MSOwinSecurity/blob/master/src/Nancy.MSOwinSecurity/NancyContextExtensions.cs

Answer (score 1):

Access Context property in your route, like

```
Get["/"] = x => "hello " + this.Context.CurrentUser.UserName;
```

The current Nancy auth system is based on type IUserIdentity, but OWIN type is ClaimsPrinciple, so you need some way to do the bridge thing, like above mentioned package MsOwinSecurity.